# Only auto-connect to net one 1 of multiple adapters on RPi

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working with Raspbian and Kali Linux on my raspberry pi, and I have multiple wireless adapters (the built-in adapter and a nicer USB adapter). Whenever I start my Pi with the adapter in, which adapter is assigned wlan0 vs. wlan1 is quite random at times it seems. Is there anyway I can tell my Pi to assign wlan0 to the built-in immediately upon boot, for example, using MAC address? Or anything else?